# Why is there a warning not to use system.cmp[string] for Nim string comparison

Tags: nim-lang

In the Nim standard library there is a [warning](http://nim-lang.org/algorithm.html):

```
 sort(myIntArray, system.cmp[int])

 # do not use cmp[string] here as we want to use the specialized
 # overload:
 sort(myStrArray, system.cmp)
```

Can anyone provide more explanation for this?

### What I've tried

1. Looking in the source code

It sounds like there may be two implementations of sort, a normal one and a specialized one for comparing strings, but looking in the source [here](https://github.com/Araq/Nim/blob/master/lib/pure/algorithm.nim#L151) I can't find any such specialization.

2. Experimenting with the compiler

I tried writing the following program:

```
import algorithm

var strArray: array[4,string]  = ["a","ab","abcd","abc"]

sort(strArray, system.cmp[string])
# sort(strArray, system.cmp)

for x in strArray:
  echo x
```

and tried both ways of doing the comparison.  However, when I compared the generated C code there did not seem to be any significant differences.  The output of fc is shown below, but to my eye it just looks like unimportant changes:

```
Comparing files NIMCACHE\testsorta.c and NIMCACHE\TESTSORT.C
***** NIMCACHE\testsorta.c
typedef struct {
N_NIMCALL_PTR(NI, ClPrc) (NimStringDesc* x_91042, NimStringDesc* y_91044, void*
ClEnv);
void* ClEnv;
} TY91048;
typedef N_CLOSURE_PTR(NI, TMP153) (NimStringDesc* x_91025, NimStringDesc* y_9102
7, void* ClEnv);
struct  tcell44933  {
***** NIMCACHE\TESTSORT.C
typedef struct {
N_NIMCALL_PTR(NI, ClPrc) (NimStringDesc* x_91054, NimStringDesc* y_91056, void*
ClEnv);
void* ClEnv;
} TY91060;
typedef N_CLOSURE_PTR(NI, TMP153) (NimStringDesc* x_91037, NimStringDesc* y_9103
9, void* ClEnv);
struct  tcell44933  {
*****

***** NIMCACHE\testsorta.c
N_NIMCALL(void, genericAssign)(void* dest, void* src, TNimType* mt);
N_NIMCALL(void, sort_91029)(NimStringDesc** a_91037, NI a_91037Len0, TY91048 cmp
_91047, NU8 order_91050);
N_NIMCALL(void, merge_91090)(NimStringDesc** a_91098, NI a_91098Len0, NimStringD
esc** b_91106, NI b_91106Len0, NI lo_91110, NI
m_91112, NI hi_91114, TY91048 cmp_91122, NU8 order_91125);
N_NIMCALL(NI, cmp_4517)(NimStringDesc* x, NimStringDesc* y);
N_NIMCALL(NimStringDesc*, copyStringRC1)(NimStringDesc* src);
***** NIMCACHE\TESTSORT.C
N_NIMCALL(void, genericAssign)(void* dest, void* src, TNimType* mt);
N_NIMCALL(NI, cmp_91024)(NimStringDesc* x_91028, NimStringDesc* y_91030);
N_NIMCALL(void, sort_91041)(NimStringDesc** a_91049, NI a_91049Len0, TY91060 cmp
_91059, NU8 order_91062);
N_NIMCALL(void, merge_91102)(NimStringDesc** a_91110, NI a_91110Len0, NimStringD
esc** b_91118, NI b_91118Len0, NI lo_91122, NI
m_91124, NI hi_91126, TY91060 cmp_91134, NU8 order_91137);
N_NIMCALL(NimStringDesc*, copyStringRC1)(NimStringDesc* src);
*****

***** NIMCACHE\testsorta.c
NIM_EXTERNC N_NOINLINE(void, testsortInit)(void) {
        TY91048 LOC1;
        nimfr("testsort", "testsort.nim")
***** NIMCACHE\TESTSORT.C
NIM_EXTERNC N_NOINLINE(void, testsortInit)(void) {
        TY91060 LOC1;
        nimfr("testsort", "testsort.nim")
*****

***** NIMCACHE\testsorta.c
        memset((void*)(&LOC1), 0, sizeof(LOC1));
        LOC1.ClPrc = ((TMP153) (cmp_4517)); LOC1.ClEnv = NIM_NIL;
        sort_91029(strarray_91015, 4, LOC1, ((NU8) 1));
        {
***** NIMCACHE\TESTSORT.C
        memset((void*)(&LOC1), 0, sizeof(LOC1));
        LOC1.ClPrc = ((TMP153) (cmp_91024)); LOC1.ClEnv = NIM_NIL;
        sort_91041(strarray_91015, 4, LOC1, ((NU8) 1));
        {
*****
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [`proc cmp[T](x, y: T): int`](http://nim-lang.org/system.html#cmp,T,T)

> [`proc cmp(x, y: string): int`](http://nim-lang.org/system.html#cmp,string,string)
>
> Compare proc for strings. More efficient than the generic version.

This is the difference. `cmp(s1, s2)` is more efficient than `cmp[string](s1, s2)`.

The reason why you don't see any difference in generated code is because one version has `cmp(string, string)` turned into a C function, and the other one has the generic instantiated as `cmp[string](string, string)` into a C function, and the signatures of these are exactly the same. You should look for differences in the bodies of these functions, which should be in `system.c`.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!  You are quite right, if I compare stdlib_system.c then I do indeed see a slow version generated if I use the wrong function - it all makes sense now :)